# Is it possible to hold my wand in my left hand?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

By default, my character is right handed and holds the wand in his right hand.

Is there a way I can change my character to be left handed and hold the wand in my left hand?

Comment: Not sure why multiple people downvoted this, if there is something wrong with the question add a comment or flag it when appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, various sources on [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/990080/discussions/0/3761104049342814089/) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HarryPotterGame/comments/10xbqs5/options_for_left_wand_hand/) seem to indicate that this is not possible. You can only be right-handed. I also looked through the game's settings and I don't see anything.

You can only customize your wand's style, wood, flexibility, length, and core. Changing the wand hand is not an option as of today.